# How to run command in Screen with parameters

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run a command on detached Screen. The problem is that it does not work when the command has additional parameters, e. g.:

```
screen -L "ls"
```

It produces a file (screenlog.0) with directory listing. But when I'm running

```
screen -L "ls -la"
```

Screen fails with error: `Cannot exec 'ls -la': No such file or directory`

Is there any way to run it properly in a Screen session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use screen without quotes, then should be ok.